# How do I know what the exception is in Eclipse, Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, stack-trace

The biggest annoyance so far is that I just cannot see what the heck happened if there is an exception. In Visual Studio if an exception happens, even if it happened somewhere in the underlying libraries, the last executed line of my code is highlighted yellow, and I can see what the exception is.

I know I'm missing something basic, but Eclipse just shows me the "Source Not Found" message, I have a stack trace with a bunch of functions that are useless because none of them are mine, but the main bummer is that I'm just unable to find any information about the exception being thrown, and it frustrates the hell out of me.

The LogCat panel has nothing about the exception in it, the console window has nothing about the exception in it, but I know it should be there somewhere, please help me find it.

Comment: If nothing is showing up in LogCat how do you know an exception is being thrown? Are you seeing other log messages from your app in LogCat?

Comment: If you got an exception it is in the logcat. Try [creating a LogCat filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050601/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-log-messages-from-our-own-application-in-android/7050610#7050610) with the tag `AndroidRuntime`. This way you can find it immediately.

Comment: You should add your LogCat output anyways, sometimes you just forgot to add an Activity or something to the Manifest-file or didn't call a super-method.

Comment: Maybe it is not a Android stacktrace but a Eclipse stacktrace?

Comment: The LogCat has no exception info whatsoever, none.

Comment: Kristian, ARE THERE SEVERAL STACKTRACES???

Comment: You can try here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624309/android-stack-trace-where-is-error-shown/7624437

I recommend you to use the LogCat.

Comment: Giancarlo Calderón Cárdenas, thank you! Now I got the LogCat to display my exception, but I had to press F6(Step over) 5 or 6 times. I guess my problem was that I expected the exception to bubble up from the underlying code, which apparently it doesn't, Eclipse suspends right there where it happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can try here. It is asked a related question.

[Android Stack Trace - Where is error shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624309/android-stack-trace-where-is-error-shown/7624437)

I recommend you using the LogCat.You activate it in

Window --> Show View --> Other --> Android --> LogCat.

If an exception is thrown, the log show it in red. In my experience, the real problem never appear at the beginning of the exception, it appears after the line

"Caused By"

There you will see in which line in your code the exception was generated and be able to go there by simply double clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

go through the stack trace from top to bottom. it's very likely, that at some point you will find a reference to your code, which triggered an exception.

generally, if you are going to program java it's very important to understand how exceptions work and how to read stack traces.

you can check this tutorial:
http://www.0xcafefeed.com/2004/06/of-thread-dumps-and-stack-traces/

Answer (score 0):

I found out the name of the exception from the stack trace, but it's all I could get, still no clue to what's causing it and where it happens. So here's what I'm doing (lstItems is a ListView control in my activity:

```
cursor = adapter.fetchAllItems();   //that's a simple database adapter
            int a = cursor.getCount();
            if (cursor.getCount()!=0)
                {
                    startManagingCursor(cursor);
                    String[] from = new String[] { adapter.KEY_NAME};
                    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.listView1 };
                    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
                    {                       

                        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                R.layout.manageItems, cursor, from, to);                        
                        lstItems.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);  //that's what causing the exception, if I comment this line out, everything's fine, but the list is not updated either.

                    }                   
                }
```

So the code runs, and when the activity with the updated ListView is supposed to show up, the debugger stops with  the following stack trace:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
    ListView.layoutChildren() line: 1662    
    ListView(AbsListView).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1147  
    ListView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035    
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1249 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1125    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1042   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035    
    FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333 
    FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035 
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1249 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1125    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1042   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333  
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035   
    ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1045 
    ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1727  
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I figured that happens because I'm doing something wrong with the UI thread, but I have no idea what. I'm not using multiple threads at all.

Comment: Add this extra information to your question, instead of posting it as an answer.